# Should I duplicate entity model?

Tags: java, jpa, optimization, entity, persistence

In my application, there are entities. but some entities need implement interface. 
for example,
I have "Course", "Lesson" entities. I have created "CourseService" , "LessonService" interfaces and "CourseServiceImpl", "LessonServiceImpl".
But the problem is my "Course" and "Lesson" should implement "Payable" interface. 
what should I do? duplicate my entities?

Thank you,

Comment: Why dont you just add on your `Course` and `Lesson` interfaces the `extends Payable` ? That way, you'll have your entities that would be `Payable` Though, as far as design is concerned, I would strongly recommand not to use such solution as it is better for entities to have no intelligence in their code.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Why don't you just let `Course` and `Lesson` implement the `Payable` interface?

Comment: @HBo , Course, and Lesson are the entity classes. if I implement the Payable interface, they will contain methods from the Payable interface.is it the right contain business methods in entity classes?

Comment: @ElvinAliyev kind of the point, yes. But you really should build an example showing us what you did, what's wrong, and what you tried to correct it. Other than that, it's just guess after guess...

Comment: @DamCx could you explain why entities should have no intelligence in their code? Preferably with reference to a recognized methodology. The ones I know (most notably DDD) say the exact opposite

Comment: @crizzis DDD is a specific way to design code and entites. Most of the time, JPA entities are generated, so you don't want to have intelligence in them, so you are sure you won't miss a thing or break your code somehow.

Comment: @DamCx 'Most of the time, JPA entities are generated' sounds pretty anecdotal, and if I were to provide my own anecdotal evidence, it would point towards the conclusion that most of the time, entities are *not* generated. All I wanted to point out is that your comment made it sound like there was a technical limitation in JPA or a universal consensus in the industry that entities should not contain logic, neither of which is actually the case.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. I presume your `Payable` interface has method `pay()`. Implement it in both your entities. If the implementations are different, you're fine. If they are the same, you could extract it into another object and encapsulate it in `Course` and `Lesson`. Or not - there's nothing wrong with duplicating code per se - only with code that is difficult to change and extend. We have the DRY principle - Don't Repeat Yourself. I prefer DRINK - Do Repeat If Necessary, Kay? :) (Not sure who coined it though).

Anyway, I would recommend having as little code in services as possible. You will have higher [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) if your entities can perform their responsibilities themselves and don't expose their internal structure to some service. Martin Fowler [explains it quite well](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). Also, [this](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html).